# Github user email is null, despite user:email scope

Tags: github-api

I am following [Github’s OAuth flow](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/), and obtaining an access token that gives me access to the user’s email scope.  When I exchange a code for an access token, using the https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token endpoint, I get the following response:

```
{
  access_token: '83f42..xxx’,
  token_type: 'bearer',
  scope: 'user:email' 
}
```

Looks great.  So I make this request, using the token to get my user data:

```
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept: application/json
Authorization: token 83f42..xxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

GET https://api.github.com/user
```

I do get my user object as a response, but the email property is null.  Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I found out why this occurs and how to resolve it. According to the [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user):

> Note: The returned email is the user's publicly visible email address
>   (or `null` if the user has not specified a public email address in their
>   profile).

In your GitHub profile settings, under **Public email**, some users (including myself) have that option set to "Don't show my email address." The call to `/user` only returns the public email address, so if the user doesn't want it shown, the API will respect that.

[image]

To get the user's email addresses regardless of whether or not they are public, use the call to [`/user/emails`](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/emails/#list-email-addresses-for-a-user). You would use the access token in exactly the same way as the `/user` request:

```
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept: application/json
Authorization: token 83f42..xxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

GET https://api.github.com/user/emails
```

This call gave me the following JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "primary": true,
    "verified": true
  }
]
```

Comment: Using node.js with passport-github, the solution is to pass `scope: [ 'user:email' ]` to the GitHubStrategy constructor. Note that you will get an array of the user's emails, filter for `primary: true` if you want to, etc.

Comment: @AntonDrukh could you elaborate? what would the `passport-github` incantation be?

Comment: @Fergie see my answer below, too long for a comment.

Comment: @AntonDrukh Cheers!

Comment: Is it possible to get the users name and a non-public email in one API call?

Comment: @IvanKuckir I don't believe so. The [/user](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user) endpoint "provides publicly available information about someone with a GitHub account." You'll need to make another API call to retrieve private emails.

Comment: @LevBuchel Where did you find that? On [the blog](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param), it states that authentication through query parameters is being deprecated, not this request. This particular example performs basic authentication using headers and should continue to work after July 1st, 2020.

Comment: If a user is seeing some site's OAuth report "your email address couldn't be fetched" from GitHub, is there something that user (me) can do in GitHub to overcome the problem?

Comment: @MikeC I would contact the website, as that appears to be a custom error message that could mean anything. It seems like it might be a failure message.

Answer (score 10):

Couldn't fit this into a comment, so answering for the node.js `passport-github` case:

```
var GitHubStrategy = require('passport-github').Strategy;

passport.use('github-login', new GitHubStrategy({
  clientID: config.clientId,
  clientSecret:  config.secret,
  callbackURL: config.host + config.callback,
  passReqToCallback: true, // req object on auth is passed as first arg
  scope: [ 'user:email' ], // fetches non-public emails as well
},
  function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // find user by profile and update it
    // or create the user object given the req, tokens and profile objs
    // don't forget to call `done(null, user)` once done
}
));
```

Comment: The whole point of this question is that in some cases requesting the 'user:email' scope is not enough -- you will still get a null email for some users. @Alexander's answer covers this use case and can be seen as complementary to your answer in the case where the returned profile's email is null.

Comment: For passport, one can specify the `scope` in the `authorize` call too. That seems to work for Google and Facebook, but doesn't work for GitHub. This approach worked for GitHub. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make an extra request to `https://api.github.com/user/emails` with the access token.

**Here is the full Authentication Flow:**

1. To get the "Code", first redirect the user to
   `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id={CLIENTID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URL}&scope=read:user,user:email`
2. Then to get the Access Token, make a POST request with the "Code" you received, like so:
   `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id={clientID}&client_secret={clientSecret}&code={code}`
3. Now when you when you receive the access token, first make a request to the `/user` endpoint, and then make a request to the `/user/emails` endpoint. Make sure you pass the access token in the header with parameter `Authorization: "token {accessToken}"`

To get the basic user data make a GET request to this url:
`https://api.github.com/user`

And then to get the user emails, make a GET request to `https://api.github.com/user/emails`

You may get multiple emails in your result. The result will look something like this:

```
[
  {
    email: 'johndoe100@gmail.com',
    primary: true,
    verified: true,
    visibility: 'public'
  },
  {
    email: 'johndoe111@domain.com',
    primary: false,
    verified: true,
    visibility: null
  }
]
```

You can select the one that has the `primary` parameter set to `true`.